# jquery keyup and mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
<input class="quantity" type="text"  value="33000">
<script>    
   $(document).ready(
   $('.quantity').keyup(function (event) {
       alert('up');
       MyVeryImportantValidate($(this), event.key)                  
   });
   ..
</script>
```

My problem, if introduced into the Input still holding the keys and mouse make click on any other element in page... event **keyup** does not work.

Comment: Why would a user be holding a key ***and*** be clicking on another element at the same time? Anyway, use the keydown event instead!

Comment: is not useCase. just to break the system. MyVeryImportantValidate not call and this very bad

Comment: You may call "MyVeryImportantValidate" on blur of $('.quantity')

Comment: You can't rely on clientside validation, so it shouldn't be "very bad"!

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation in jquery states it clearly, it is going to the item that has focus.

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on
>   the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only
>   sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can vary
>   between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

In fact the focus is lost even on holding a key down in this input text area.  If I hold down the a letter key it repeats until I click outside it changing the focus.